# How to create a share button in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

How can I create a share button, and also get count for each post shared?

Comment: What kind of share Button you will implement?

Comment: share button for users to be able to share post

Comment: So you don't mean a social media share button. But only a button that gives you a link to the current post?

Comment: yes exactly what I needed

Comment: What would be counted?

Comment: How do you define a post shared? What should be counted exactly?

Comment: This is a serious question for Digital marketers. The greatest achievement would be able to track different share ids for the post/shared item. Like: create a link with a generated id->(www.post.com/posts/{post_data}/followup/{follow_up_id}) then create a method to capture visits of a given post which have different follow_up_id. this way you can be able to tell which post has what effective shares. On this much can be achieved esp with assessing marketers performance and reach. Great question

Answer (score 0):

In your Blade file that outputs the article, you can output a button. this contains a hidden textarea as a child element. With JS you can put a click event listener on it.

So you can copy the URL to the post. I hope I have understood it correctly?

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e)
{   
  const textArea = document.createElement("textarea");
  textArea.value = e.target.querySelector('.url-container').innerHTML;
  document.body.appendChild(textArea);
  textArea.select();
  let successful = null;
  let msg = '';
      
  try {
    successful = document.execCommand('copy');
    msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';    
  } catch (err) {
    console.warning('unable to copy');
    console.warning(err);
  }  
  
  document.body.removeChild(textArea);
  if (successful) {
    alert('copied');
    // make an XHR call to your App Api for counting
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="share" data-test="test"><textarea class="url-container" style="display:none;">www.your-domain.com/your-post-x</textarea>Share Post X</button>
```

Comment: this actually is not accurate. what if i click share and never paste it in any of my social??

Comment: @wanjaswilly This is difficult to check, perhaps with a unique query parameter. If this is really clicked, the link can then be counted in the Laravel app.

Comment: check my comment on the question itself

Comment: @wanjaswilly The question was: "How can I create a share button, and also get count for each post shared?"  What you mean is an analysis. That was not clear from the question and is, in my opinion, a different topic. 
And of course, tracking and analysis is an important topic.